# The schema returned by query is differ from base query

Tags: vb.net

When I Tried to add query by "Query Builder" after selecting data adapter and data set from datagrid view I receive this error "the schema returned by query is differ from base query"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a TableAdapter in a dataset in the designer, the primary query establishes the columns that can be returned as a part of that specific TableAdapter. If you're getting this error then the new query you're adding doesn't match the columns of the original. For instance, if you establish a dataset with this original query:

```
Select UserId, UserName, UserCreated
From Users
```

and then try to add the following query:

```
Select UserId, UserName, NumberOfFailedLogins
```

you'll get this error because the queries don't match what they return. The "Add Query" feature really is meant to group sql queries for like requirements (e.g. CRUD, filtered searches, etc).