# vb.net "the schema returned by query is differ from base query" in winforms

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am working on vb.net windows application. When I Tried to add query by "Query Builder" after selecting data adapter and data set from datagrid view I receive this error:

```
the schema returned by query is differ from base query
```

MY QUERY IS LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT        
    CompanyMaster_tbl.CompanyName, 
    DepartmentMaster_tbl.dtName, 
    DepartmentMaster_tbl.dtPhone, 
    DepartmentMaster_tbl.dtEmail
FROM            
    CompanyMaster_tbl 
    INNER JOIN DepartmentMaster_tbl ON CompanyMaster_tbl.Cid = DepartmentMaster_tbl.cId
```

First I added the company name to datagrid view choosing the data source and particular table name but while clicking Ok button am getting the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The schema returned by query is differ from base query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718525/the-schema-returned-by-query-is-differ-from-base-query)

Comment: but sir still am getting the same error,,can u please check my query

Comment: @user3106114 did you try what was suggested in the other thread Roger linked to?  You get this error when you try to add a query which has different columns to the one specified by the table adapter, so look to that and either change the query in the table adapter or the one you've specified above.  Syntactically speaking there's nothing wrong with your query, it's just different from what the adapter is expecting, hence the error.

Comment: sir,,this query is automatically generating while am selecting field in Table adapter,,